# Invalid Hook Error, Duplicate version of react?

Tags: reactjs, npm, dom, react-router, react-router-dom

I am getting an invalid hook error whenever using anything imported from react-router-dom, such as Router and Route

I got the same invalid hook error when using styled-components, but by re-installing it and forcing it to fix in the command line the error went away. That did not work for this

What should I do to fix it? Do I have duplicate versions of react?

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here are my npm packages
[npm list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwMAa.png)

Comment: `react-router-dom` doesn't appear to be a dependency in your project. Try installing it by running `npm i -S react-router-dom@latest` and then restart your app to see if any issues persist.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the package-lock.json and node-modules folder. Then add react-router-dom: "6.3.0" or whatever version you would like to the package.json if it isn't already there.

Restart your IDE and npm install in the terminal

Answer (score -1):

I don't see react-router-dom in your packages.

1. `npm i react-router-dom --force`
2. If that doesn't work, instead of importing, use require. Like this: `const {BrowserRouter: Router, Routes, Route} = require("react-router-dom")`;
   Also when you imported Router, did you make sure you wrote `BrowserRouter as Router` or `BrowserRouter: Router` (for require)?

Because react-router-dom doesn't export Router, it exports BrowserRouter, so if you want to use Router you must say Router as BrowserRouter or the other way for require.